# Avoid writing SQL statements in MATLAB code

Tags: sql, matlab, business-logic

I'm working on an app with complicated interrelationships between the set value of some controls and the allowed values of other controls.

The logic controlling those interrelationships is suppose to be stored in a sqlite database.

So my storyboard code has lots of instances of things like

```matlab
% Extract the coordinates of this location
q = sprintf("%s %s %s '%s';" ...
    , "SELECT latitude, longitude, altitude " ...
    , "FROM locale" ...
    , "WHERE name = " ...
    , app.LocationDropDown.Value ...
    );
llaTbl = app.queryDB(q);
```

or worse (the `sprintf` running to ten or more lines and using three or more parameters).

This has all the usual problems of putting business logic in code with the added bonus that the limitation of Matlab's string literals syntax and parameter replacement system make it painful and error-prone to try to cut-n-paste this to or from a SQL test environment.

What mechanisms are there to centralize the storage and editing or query texts that make testing as painless as reasonably achievable?

Answer (score 0):

I'm testing out an experimental option, and thought I'd add it here for completeness.

### Storing the queries in the DB itself

That is, I've added a table to the schema (that has no relationship with the other tables except at the meta level that those other tables are references in the stored queries.<sup>1</sup>

#### How well does it solve the problem

The things that it *does*:

1. separate the business logical from the code.
2. allow me to cut-n-paste queries to a test environment pretty easily (though I have to type in the parameters values by hand).
3. simplifies the main code base, as the code in the question is replaced by

   `llaTbl = app.getFromDB('latlongByLocale',app.LocationDropDown.Value);`

Things it *doesn't* do:

1. Solve the "very long lines or nasty syntax" problem. SQL also doesn't have a great syntax for multi-line string literals.

#### What does it look like?

For now I am building the database by hand, so `queryStore.sql` looks likw

```
-- Experimental idea to store the queries that the app will use on
-- the main database in an auxiliary table inside the database.

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS qstore ( name TEXT NOT NULL
                                  , nparam INT
                                  , querytext TEXT
                                  , comment TEXT
                                  );

INSERT INTO qstore VALUES ( 'localesInRegion', 1
                          , "SELECT locale.name as name FROM locale JOIN region ON locale.regionID = region.id WHERE region.name = '%s';"
                          , ""
                          );
INSERT INTO qstore VALUES ( 'regionMapData', 1
                          , "SELECT mapformat, maprights, mapfile FROM region WHERE name = '%s';"
                          , ""
                          );
INSERT INTO qstore VALUES ( 'localeMapData', 1
                          , "SELECT mapformat, maprights, mapfile FROM locale WHERE name = '%s';"
                          , ""
                          );                          
INSERT INTO qstore VALUES ( 'latlongByLocale', 1
                          , "SELECT latitude, longitude, altitude FROM locale  WHERE name = '%s';"
                          , ""
                          );
```

And the retrieval in matlab is mediated by a set of functions including

```matlab
function str = parameterizeQuery(app, qname, varargin)
% Retrieve parameterized query from the DB and perform string
% substitution.

% Get the querytext and expected number of parameters making sure the 
% result is non-null
q = sprintf("SELECT nparam, querytext FROM qstore WHERE name = '%s';",qname);
tbl = app.queryDB(q);
if isempty(tbl)
    error('storyboard2:parameterizeQuery:nomatch'...
        ,"No query stroed in the dabase by name '%s'.",qname);
end

nparam = tbl.nparam(1);
querytext = tbl.querytext{1};
if nparam ~= nargin - 2
    warning('storyboard2:parameterizeQuery:wrongParameterCount'...
        ,"The number of parameters passed does not match the number in the query retrieved. Hoping for the best.");
end
% insert parameters
str = sprintf(querytext,varargin{:});
end

function tbl = getFromDB(app, qname, varargin)
% A pass-through convenience function that calls
% parameterizeQuery() and passes the result to
% queryDB()
str = app.parameterizeQuery(qname, varargin{:});
tbl = app.queryDB(str);
end
```

---

<sup>1</sup> I'm a little worried that this is an instance of every problem looking like it fits my hammer, or some such.